# How to filter array by array using javascript with duplicate key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 array and i will filtered but key duplicate.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4];
const arr2 = [1, 3];

function filteredArray(arr1, arr2) {...}

const newArr = filteredArray(arr1, arr2);

console.log(newArr);

// result: [2, 3, 3, 4];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the below implementation. We should not modify the original data as well, that's why I've cloned your array for the array modification instead of changing items on the original one.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4];
const arr2 = [1, 3];

function filteredArray(arr1, arr2) {
  const newArr1 = [...arr1] //clone the array to keep the original array data
  const set2 = new Set(arr2)
  for(let i = 0; i < newArr1.length; i++) {
     if(set2.has(newArr1[i])) {
        set2.delete(newArr1[i])
        newArr1.splice(i,1)
     }
  }
  return newArr1
}

const newArr = filteredArray(arr1, arr2);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but sorry, result not expected.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question, let me try to arrange my answer again @joysahimar

Answer (score 0):

Use `set` and `filter`

```js
function filteredArray(arr1, arr2) {
  const set = new Set(arr2);
  return arr1.filter(item => !set.delete(item));
}

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4];
const arr2 = [1, 3];

console.log(filteredArray(arr1, arr2));
```